# Are there 2 saiyans called Panpukin in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

According to the spanish Dragon Ball Wikia, the name of this saiyan is Panpukin (the one who fought Tien, Yamcha, etc.)

[image]

and also according to the same Wikia, this another saiyan who was a friend of Bardock is also called Panpukin

[image]

is this right or it's a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is called [Scarface](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Scarface) (パンプキン Panpukin, lit. "Pumpkin") and second one is called [Shugesh](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Shugesh) (パンブーキン, Panbūkin).

Comment: The first is a pun on Pumpkin and the second a pun on what?